# How to use List.RemoveAll to remove given a certain criteria

Tags: c#, list

I am writing a fluid simulation in which I need, for each particle, a list of neighboring particles within a radius, R.

If have a list of potential neighbors, how would I remove all the potential neighbors based on a distance criteria?

I am currently doing this with a for loop but this seems slow and inefficient.
My current method in psuedo code is:

```
temp = getPotentialNeighbors(point);

        foreach(Particle n in temp)
        {
            if(Distance(n.Pos,point.Pos)<radius)
                neighbors.Add(n);
        }
```

Comment: where are you (on which line) removing item?

Comment: Check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069431/listobject-removeall-how-to-create-an-appropriate-predicate

Comment: I am taking it from a temp list and adding ones to the neighbor list

Comment: @vgSefa Thank you, I seemed to miss that. I am reading through it now

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to get all the items that match the predicate and put them into a new list, you can do it like that:

```
var newList = temp.Where(p => Distance(p,point) < radius).ToList();
```

To remove the items from the `temp` list, you can do like that:

```
temp.RemoveAll(p => Distance(p,point) < radius);
```

This passes a predicate `to RemoveAll()` and it will remove all items that match the condition given by the predicate.

Regarding performance I don't think this would be any better than your version with a loop, but this is shorter and easier.

Comment: The list is storing a class called Particle, so you have to access the position from the class. I tried this


`temp.RemoveAll(x => Distance(point.Pos,x.Pos)<radius);`
but it through an error saying                           
"Error CS1061: 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Particle>' does not contain a definition for 'Pos' and no extension method 'Pos' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Particle>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: `x.Pos` should be the `radius` argument you supplied yourself in your sample code in the question.

Comment: So you want to get a list of Pos properties from the objects? You can use the Select() LINQ mechanism like this: 

var newList = temp.Where(p => Distance(p,point) < radius).Select(p => p.Pos).ToList();

This will return you a list of Pos properties from the objects.

Comment: @msporek No, I want to get a list of the potential neighbors their Pos is within a certain radius